# HP ProBook custom boot logo

Tags: efi

my HP ProBook 5420s supports custom boot logo but I can't get it working.

It has UEFI (not BIOS), custom boot logo option is on and I have placed a 1366x768 (native.. also tried 1024x768 as guide told so) bitmap to HP_TOOLS\Hewlett-Packard\Logo\Hplogo.bmp according to HP UEFI guide I have found: http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01564727.pdf

Comment: UEFI is not a type of BIOS - it's an alternative/replacement for BIOS firmware.

Comment: On older bios's they have to be an uncompressed bitmap image of a certain file size or less, even then some images will not load into the memory space provided for custom images, it can take some trial and error. Can you post the guide?

Comment: @paradroid, in reality it is a bios, just nothing like the original IBM version, it is still referred to as a bios in all documentation from Dell, HP etc...http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&docname=c01443329

Comment: @Moab: I would imagine they have done that to make user-support less confusing.

Comment: @paradroid They are both firmware, they both run code from the MBR, they both hand off hardware to the OS, they are basically the same thing, just different terminology and some improved technology. Lets not get too picky now.

Comment: @Moab: I have posted link to the guide in my question

Comment: Ooops, sorry, is it an uncompressed bitmat you are using?

Comment: it has 3MB.. solid regions.. I think it is uncompressed bitmap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The HP UEFI custom logo needs to be a 1024x768 JPG, Hplogo.jpg, not BMP as the guide suggests.

Answer (score 0):

To get a fullscreen logo on an EliteBook that is not stretched, you need to make your final jpg 800x768 so it’s displayed correct.