# HP Elitebook 8570w custom boot logo

Tags: boot, partitioning, hp-elitebook

I'm trying to get a custom boot logo to work, but I have to place it on the HP_Tools partition. I cannot see this partition, neither from Windows' partition manager and from EaseUS Partition Master.

How do I get my custom boot logo to work?

I already know the requirements for the image:

- .jpg file format
- Resolution range between 424 x 320 pixels and 1024 x 768 pixels
- File size maximum of 32 kilobytes
- Maximum of 16 million colors

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to get the boot logo working (how I did it):

- Verify that you have a HP_TOOLS partition, see NikolaD's answer how to do so.
- If not, use the following install program to create the partition (sp60844.exe) http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?swItem=ob-116962-1&ac.admitted=1381442205113.876444892.492883150
- Another way (not verified myself) is to create the partition yourself. It should be called 'HP_TOOLS' without the quotes, 2 gigabytes and formatted as FAT32.
- The logo should be *at most* 1024x768 pixels, jpg format, at most 32 kilobytes in size.
- Save the boot-logo to HP_TOOLS/Hewlett-Packard/Logo/Hplogo.jpg - where HP_TOOLS is the root of the HP_TOOLS partition.
- Reboot the laptop, go to the BIOS via F12 → System Configuration → Custom Logo → Enabled (might be blocked by other BIOS settings) → Save and exit.
- Reboot and you will see your custom boot logo.

This works for my HP Elitebook 8570w, but I cannot guarantee it will work for every Elitebook.

Sources:

- NikolaD's answer
- http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-Systems-and-Software/How-can-i-create-hp-tools-partition-for-hp-quick-web/td-p/2567373
- [HP ProBook custom boot logo](https://superuser.com/questions/216042/hp-probook-custom-boot-logo)
- http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01564727.pdf
- and maybe some others..

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how you will enter the custom logo, but I can help you to make the HP recovery partition visible

1. Press <kbd>[image: Win]</kbd> key, type `cmd` in the Search field and
   press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. Type `diskpart` in Command prompt
3. Type `list disk`
4. Select the disk (In my case i have only one HDD and it is **disk
   0**)
5. Type `select disk 0` (number 0 is valid in my case, in your case it
   could be different)
6. Type `list partition`. It will list all partitions for selected disk (0 in my
   case and my recovery partition is **Partition 4**)
7. Type `select partition 4` (enter your partition number instead of 4)
8. Type `assign` (and press  <kbd>Enter</kbd> of course :)

[image: diskpart steps image]

And your partition is now visible !!

Comment: Nope, only 2 partitions appear. The primary (OS) and the data partition. No recovery, nothing :(

Comment: Than you have only these two partitions :(

Comment: In such case you will have to create the HP_Tools partition. Check this http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-Systems-and-Software/How-can-i-create-hp-tools-partition-for-hp-quick-web/td-p/2567373 topic on HP support forum

Comment: Thanks, this link got me to download the following file: http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?cc=nl&lc=nl&dlc=nl&softwareitem=ob-80561-1. I followed all instructions and it created a new partition. I'll try to get the logo working later today. I'll let you know if it worked :)

Comment: I'm glad you made it :) Cheers!